# how to change date format in "zend_log"

Tags: php, zend-log

How can I change date format of the Zend_Log?

Now there is date with timestamp added in front of every new log entry:
"2013-01-28T16:47:54+01:00 ... some log message ..."

But I would like to format this date like:
"Y-m-d H:i:s ... some log message ..."

My code looks like this:

```
class Game_Logger {

    public function __construct($val, $txt = null) {
        $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../log/log.log');
        $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $output = Zend_Debug::dump($val, null, false);
        } else {
            $output = $val;
        }
        if($txt){
            $output = $txt.' '.$output;
        }
        $logger->info($output);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably this will resolve your problem:

`$logger->setTimestampFormat("H:i:s");`
but something tells me you already figured it out ;).

Comment: Of course you need to update format to this one you actually want.

Comment: Yes, this indeed resolved my problem. I didn't have time to figure it out and it wasn't a blocker so I just waited for someone to answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Zend Framework 2 and 3, below code might be help

```
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();

    $formatter = new  \Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple();
    $formatter->setDateTimeFormat('Y-m-d'); // as per your choice

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
    $writer->setFormatter($formatter);
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
```